# How to extract the p-value from the lm function within the apply function?

Tags: r, apply, lm, p-value

I am repeating the lm function over about 700,000 columns. I'm using the apply function to repeat lm over the columns in my data. Then I need to extract all the pvalues. When I print the summary of the lm function, the pvalue is listed under Pr(>|t|).

I have tried using `pvals <- sapply(result,"[[", "p.value")` but it results in NULL.

This is the code that prints the lm summary for 3 columns right now (I'm using a smaller file to test).

```
result <- apply(dat4[,-c(1:27)], 2, function(x) {
  summary(lm(x ~ total + age + female + diagnosis_MDD + diagnosis_BP))
})
result
```

This is the output of just one column:

```
$cg05451842

Call:
lm(formula = x ~ total + age + female + diagnosis_MDD + diagnosis_BP)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.008621 -0.002647  0.001077  0.002979  0.006320 

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    2.658e-02  3.428e-03   7.753 1.72e-09 
total         -3.603e-04  1.007e-03  -0.358   0.7224    
age           -1.123e-04  6.765e-05  -1.659   0.1049    
female         7.997e-04  1.268e-03   0.631   0.5318    
diagnosis_MDD -3.487e-03  1.534e-03  -2.273   0.0285   
diagnosis_BP  -1.692e-03  1.586e-03  -1.067   0.2926


Signif. codes:  0      0.001      0.01     0.05     0.1     1

Residual standard error: 0.004242 on 40 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1723,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.06879 
F-statistic: 1.665 on 5 and 40 DF,  p-value: 0.1654
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tidy` function from the `broom` package makes this a bit easier by generating a standard data frame of the coefficients and p-values for a given regression model. You can place all of the regression coefficients and associated p-values from all of the models into a single data frame by using `map_df` to iterate over the entire list of regression summaries and run the `tidy` function on each list element:

```
library(broom)
library(tidyverse)

regression.results = map_df(result, tidy, .id="outcome.var")
```

If you just want the p-values, you could then do:

```
p.values = regression.results %>% select(outcome.var, term, p.value)
```

Or, all in one step:

```
p.values = map_df(result, ~tidy(.x) %>% select(term, p.value), 
                  .id="outcome.var")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a list of different objects. You can call them with:

`result[[i]]`

All you have to do is getting the p-value from it. Since you want the Pr(>|t|) you can get them with:

```
result[[i]]$coefficients[c(7,8)]
```